# Procedure to insert data if not exist pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I have a table with these columns (id,first_name,birth). I want to create a procedure that insert a new customer only if the id inserted doesn't exist in the table. If it already exist, then don't insert it. This is my code so far, but I got an error 'line 3 sql statement ignored'. Any idea? I need to use procedure and pl sql in oracle. Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_emp(v_id   IN int,
                                    v_name IN varchar2,
                                    v_bday IN date) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Employees
    (Id, First_name, Birth)
    SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT v_id, v_name, v_bday) AS tmp
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Employees WHERE Id = v_id);
END;
/

DECLARE
  m_id   int := 3;
  m_name varchar2 := 'John';
  m_bday date := '16-Dec-1990';
BEGIN
  add_cust(m_id, m_name, m_bday);
END;
/
```

Comment: If ID is a PK, or at least UNIQUE, then you don't need to check it first ("if already exist, then don't insert it").  Just do the insert. If ID already exists it will throw an exception which you can handle as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure has some syntax issue which is fixed in following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_EMP (
    V_ID     IN   INT,
    V_NAME   IN   VARCHAR2,
    V_BDAY   IN   DATE
) IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (
        ID,
        FIRST_NAME,
        BIRTH
    )
        SELECT V_ID,
               V_NAME,
               V_BDAY
          FROM DUAL -- FROM clause was missing
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT ID
              FROM EMPLOYEES
             WHERE ID = V_ID
        );

END;
/
```

Also, Your calling PL/SQL block has some issues which are corrected in the following code:

```
DECLARE
    M_ID     INT := 3;
    M_NAME   VARCHAR2(10) := 'John'; -- varchar2 must be declared with size
    M_BDAY   DATE := DATE '1990-12-16'; -- added date literal to convert string to date
BEGIN
    ADD_CUST(M_ID, M_NAME, M_BDAY);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SELECT does not work without a FROM clause (other DBMS products are different). So you need to provide a table; you can use DUAL, which is a dummy table provided by Oracle which is guaranteed to return one row.

```
INSERT INTO Employees(Id,First_name,Birth)
SELECT v_id, v_name, v_bday 
from dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Id FROM Employees WHERE Id = v_id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT statement would work with a slight change

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_emp(v_id   Employees.Id%type,
                                    v_name Employees.First_name%type,
                                    v_bday Employees.Birth%type) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Employees
    (Id, First_name, Birth)
    SELECT v_id, v_name, v_bday
      FROM dual
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Id = v_id);
END;
/
```

You can replace INSERT statement with MERGE as an alternative DML such as

```
MERGE INTO Employees e1
USING 
(SELECT v_id AS id, v_name AS First_name, v_bday AS birth
      FROM dual) e2
   ON ( e1.id = e2.id )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET e1.First_name = e2.First_name,
                              e1.Birth = e2.Birth -- If you need to change for the matching case
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT( e1.id, e1.First_name, e1.birth ) 
                       VALUES( e2.id, e2.First_name, e2.birth );
```